# how to use toWei() function in web3.js for tokens having 2 decimals?

Tags: web3js, tokens

I am trying to convert amount in wei using `web3js` function called `toWei()`.

**Here is my code:**

```
 var etherwithdrawamount1=web3Infura.utils.toWei(etherwithdrawamount, 'wei');
```

Now, the problem is that the token amount is not calculating correct, because the token has 2 decimals.

In web3 documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#towei there is no places for 2 decimals.

number - String|Number|BN: The value.

unit - String (optional, defaults to "ether"): The ether to convert from.

Possible units are :

```
noether: ‘0’
wei: ‘1’
kwei: ‘1000’
Kwei: ‘1000’
babbage: ‘1000’
femtoether: ‘1000’
mwei: ‘1000000’
Mwei: ‘1000000’
lovelace: ‘1000000’
picoether: ‘1000000’
gwei: ‘1000000000’
Gwei: ‘1000000000’
shannon:‘1000000000’
nanoether: ‘1000000000’
nano: ‘1000000000’
szabo: ‘1000000000000’
microether: ‘1000000000000’
micro: ‘1000000000000’
finney: ‘1000000000000000’
milliether: ‘1000000000000000’
milli: ‘1000000000000000’
ether: ‘1000000000000000000’
```

So, how to get the correct value in `toWei()` where the token decimals are 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function strtodec(amount,dec){
stringf = "";
for(var i=0;i<dec;i++){
stringf = stringf+"0";
}
return amount+stringf;
}
```

You need to call this function using this method:

```
strtodec(amount,'your token decimal here')
```

The logic is this: The function adds zeros in the amount as many as decimals you want.

Comment: what is token decimal amount or string?

Comment: You need to use the amount (integer) for whatever decimals you want :)

Comment: Good approach! But it doesn't work for doubles in JS for example `0.1`. Do you know any solution? @Yogesh-EtherAuthority.io

Answer (score 0):

This variant can work with float:

```
function strtodec(amount, dec){
    var i = 0;
    if (amount.toString().indexOf('.') != -1) {
        i = amount.toString().length - (amount.toString().indexOf('.') + 1);
    }
    stringf = amount.toString().split('.').join('');
    if (dec<i){
        console.warn("strtodec: amount was truncated")
        stringf = stringf.substring(0,stringf.length - (i-dec));
    } else {
        stringf = stringf + "0".repeat(dec-i);
    }
    return stringf;
}
```